# request.subdomain not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a new Rails Developer

My application_controller is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :sshow

  def sshow
    puts "==========================="
    puts YAML::dump(request.subdomains)
  end
end
```

now when I put kausik.localhost:3000 in my browser address bar it
returns blank Array [] instead ['kausik'] .

Also I rewrite etc/host file for this subdomain.

Comment: Avoid using `localhost:3000`, add a hosts entry or point to something like lvh.me -- Example in console: `>> app.host = 'kausik.foo.com'; app.get '/'; app.request.subdomains
=> ["kausik"]`

Answer (score 1):

As @injekt said in the comments, you can't work with subdomains using localhost. The simplest alternative is to use the `lvh.me` domain which points all subdomains to `127.0.0.1`. To do this, simply start your rails server and go to `kausik.lvh.me:3000`.

Also, if you simply need the first subdomain, you can use `request.subdomain`, which in this case would return `"kausik"`.

There's a very nice [RailsCast about subdomains in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3).